# How I can calculate the distance to a widget (top, middle and bottom of it)?

Tags: android, distance, anchorpoint

I'm developing a Slide in the bottom of my app, and it has an option of setup an anchored point, so I want to makes the slide to stay below some label everytime, so I need to calculate the point in percentage (from 0.0 to 1.0) in what the widget is.

[image: Screenshot]

How I can calculate these distances? Red, Purple and Blue lines?

Answer (score 0):

I've developed the next method in a common utils.

```
public static Point getLocationOnScreen(View view){
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    return new Point(location[0], location[1]);
}

public static Point getLocationInWindow(View view){
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationInWindow(location);
    return new Point(location[0], location[1]);
}

/**
 * Gets the device's native screen resolution rotated
 * based on the device's current screen orientation.
 */
@SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) //To remove warning about using
//getRealSize prior to API 17
public static Point screenResolution(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point screenResolution = new Point();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14)
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Android version.");
    display.getRealSize(screenResolution);

    return screenResolution;
}
```